# List all the images in view (MVP) - PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, mvp

I have worked on a small gallery app in the MVP framework (name isn't important, because it isn't famous) and I don't know, how to display all the images from /gal/ folder. I have something like this in my presenter - http://pastie.org/1595260

WWW_DIR - root dir

$gal_root - /gal/ folder in root

$gal_thumb - /gal/thumb/ - place, where the resized pictures are stored

$gal_orig - /gal/orig/ - place, where the original pictures are stored

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `$this->template` is the same as `$this->view` in Zend Framework.

Then, in your view, write :

```
foreach($this->photos as $photo){
   echo '<img src="'.$photo['thumb'].'" />'; // For thumbnail
}
```

If it's not the case, then you should give out the name of your framework or how it reacts.

Comment: Ohh, I did a small syntactic mistake, my fault, guys